# Plot percentages of two columns

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
sample_size     subject     very    not_at_all
0   2202    concern-economy     19.00   11.00
1   2202    concern-economy     26.00   7.00
2   1500    concern-infected    13.00   18.00
3   2200    concern-economy     23.00   9.00
4   1000    concern-infected    11.00   20.00
5   1500    concern-infected    11.00   22.00
9   1500    concern-infected    10.00   19.00
10  1500    concern-infected    10.00   20.00
```

Where:

- `sample_size` is the total amount of people interviewed
- `subject` is the subject of an interview
- `very` is the percentage of people that are very concerned
- `not_at_all` is the percentage of people that are not concerned at all

I would like to plot the total percentage of people interviewed on the subject "concern-infected" that are the very concerned and total percentage of not at all concerned.

I have these commands:

```
infected = concern_polls[concern_polls["subject"] == "concern-infected"]

infected.groupby('subject')[['very','not_at_all']].sum().plot.bar(rot=0)
```

But the plot represents the `very` and `not_at_all` columns as if they were integers, not percentages, and I am not sure how to output the percentages in the plot. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the labels of the plot?
This can be done like this.

```
# The steps to take as ticks
yticks = [i in range(0, 100, 20)]
yticks_labels = [str(i) + ' %' for i in yticks]

plt.yticks(yticks, yticks_labels)
```